# How to insert indent/tab in os x terminal for IronPython (ipy.exe)?

Tags: macos, mono, ironpython

I am running IronPython 2.0.2 interactive console with Mono 2.4 on OSX Terminal.app .  How do I insert indent/tab in the Terminal.app ?  I want to do this so I can indent my code.

For example I want to input

```
print "hello    tab"
```

what I see is

```
print "hellotab"
```

despite pressing the tab key many times.  When the command gets executed it prints `hellotab`.  Another weird behavior is that after pressing tab a bunch of time and then press delete the tabs shows up, but cannot be removed, and ipy still prints `hellotab` .

I tried inserting tabs with IronRuby (ir.exe) and I don't see the tab showing up when I press it, but it is displayed when the command is executed.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to insert a tab character with:

```
print "hello\ttab"
```

Although what you have above should work **if** you use a raw string, for instance:

```
print r"hello    tab"
```

Let me know if this is what you were after.

Comment: Sorry, this is not what I am looking for.  I tested \t and it doesn't print out.  I want to insert tab so I can indent my code.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the **Terminal** menu, **Preferences...** menu item.

In the Preferences dialog box, click on the **Settings** selection.

Within the settings, click on the **Keyboard** tab.

You have probably modified your tab key to not work correctly.  It should not be mentioned as a special key and should generate an ordinary tab character.

Also, run a `stty -a` command in your Terminal tool.  Someone may have changed your `oxtabs` setting or mapped tab (^I) to something unexpected.

Comment: I don't see an option to map the tab key in Terminal->Preference->Keyboard.  stty -a did not show that ^I was remaped